# ¿Cómo puedo agregar datos de un formulario a una tabla en react js?

Tags: formularios, reactjs, tablas

Necesito su ayuda, ya intenté muchas cosas pero ninguna me funciona.
Estoy intentando hacer que la información ingresada en un formulario, al hacer clic en el botón de agregar, se despliegue en una tabla.

Son 3 inputs.

En mi código ya tengo los eventos pero los hice por separado para cada input.

```
import React from 'react';

class Bookings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
          this.state = {
            value: '',
            pasajero: '',
            tour: [],
            pax: [],
            precio: [] 
          } 
          this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this) 
          this.createTour = this.createTour.bind(this); 
          this.createPax = this.createPax.bind(this);
          this.cratePrecio = this.createPrecio.bind(this);     
    }


    createTour(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            tour: this.state.tour.concat([{name: e.target.tour.value}])
        });
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    createPax(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            pax: this.state.pax.concat([{name: e.target.pax.value}])
        });
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    createPrecio(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            precio: this.state.precio.concat([{name: e.target.precio.value}])
        });
        console.log(this.state)
    }
```

Aquí agrego mi evento en onSubmit para que al hacer clic en el botón de agregar mande los datos a la tabla. Pero solo puedo poner uno de mis eventos, por lo tanto, solo me añade ese dato a la tabla.

```
<div className="inputs_tours">
                            <form  onSubmit={this.createTour} className="form_tours">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="exampleFormControlInput1">Tour:</label>
                                    <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    id="exampleFormControlInput1"
                                    name= "tour" 
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label className="exampleFormControlInput1">Pax:</label>
                                    <input 
                                    type="number" 
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    id="exampleFormControlInput1" 
                                    placeholder="#" 
                                    name= "pax"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group room">
                                    <label className="exampleFormControlInput1">Precio:</label>
                                    <input 
                                    type="number" 
                                    className="form-control" 
                                    id="exampleFormControlInput1" 
                                    placeholder="$" 
                                    name = "precio"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="pax_btn">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
                                </div>    
                            </form> 
                        </div> 

<div className="table_tours">                      
                            <table className="table table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Tour</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Pax</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Precio</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                {this.state.tour.map(t => {
                                        return(
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>{t.name}</td>                
                                    </tr>
                                );
                                })
                                }
                                {this.state.pax.map(p => {
                                        return(
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>{p.name}</td>                
                                    </tr>
                                );
                                })
                                } 
                                {this.state.precio.map(t => {
                                        return(
                                    <tr>
                                         <td>{t.name}</td>                
                                    </tr>
                                );
                                })
                                }      
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Mi duda es: ¿cómo puedo hacer para crear un evento en el que agregue los 3 datos del formulario?

Comment: En onSubmit agrega una función que llame a las otras 3. De hecho, podrías simplemente llamar una función que cambie con un solo setState los 3 campos.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma el componente funcionaria, espero te sirva.

```
import React from 'react';

class Bookings extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    tour: '',
    pax: '',
    price: ''
  };

  // Función que captura el valor de los inputs
  // para setearlo en su respectivo estado
  // Para este caso: tour, pax y price
  handleInputChange = event => {
    const { target } = event;
    const { name, value } = target;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  // Esta función se ejecutará al momento de darle click al botón de "Agregar"
  handleSubmit = event => {
    const { tour, pax, price, list } = this.state;

    // Simple validación para que tour, pax y price sean campos requeridos
    if (tour && pax && price) {
      const id = list.length + 1;
      // En los states se agrega un nuevo objeto a "list"
      // y se reinicia el estado de tour, pax y price
      this.setState({
        list: [...list, { id, tour, pax, price }],
        tour: '',
        pax: '',
        price: ''
      });
    } else {
      // Si alguno de los inputs se encuentra vacio
      // se mostrará el siguiente mensaje en la consola del navegador
      console.log('Please complete all fields');
    }

    // Para que no se refresque la página por el onSubmit del formulario
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    const { tour, pax, price, list } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="inputs_tours">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form_tours">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="tour">
                Tour:
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="tour"
                  name="tour"
                  value={tour}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="pax">
                Pax:
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="pax"
                  placeholder="#"
                  name="pax"
                  value={pax}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group room">
              <label htmlFor="price">
                Precio:
                <input
                  type="number"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="price"
                  placeholder="$"
                  name="price"
                  value={price}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="pax_btn">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="table_tours">
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Tour</th>
                <th scope="col">Pax</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {list.map(item => (
                <tr key={item.id}>
                  <td>{item.tour}</td>
                  <td>{item.pax}</td>
                  <td>{item.price}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Bookings;
```